# Genexus for Android: Can't assign SDWheel control

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I am struggeling for quite some time now because I want to implement a SDWheel control in my App.
The problem is that it isn't being assigned when trying to use it with Attributes (works fine with "Values" and "Range" though).

However, I can use "Dynamic ComboBox" with the very same configuration.

[image]

Do you have any ideia on what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Wheel control can be used only for Numeric, Date, Datetime or Enumated types.
Perhaps you're trying to use it for a Character data type.

Further information at: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?20180

Comment: The layout variable "&var" is actually "Numeric(4.0)". The value attribute "id" is also "Numeric(4.0)". Only the the description attribute "valor" is a varchar (and they are both in the same transaction).

Comment: I also tried to use DataSource from a Data Provider (as a workaround) but it didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Jaime, you're right. Attribute and DataProvider as Data Source are not implemented for Android platform yet. For Android only Range and Values are supported.
For iOS all the values as Data Source are implemented.
I apologize.